# Ionic Deploy on Android device

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

> Ionic version: 1.5.5
>
> Cordova version: 5.0.0
>
> Ionic deploy: 0.1.6

I have followed all the instructions shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8p29.jpg)

Afterwards, ran:

```
ionic build android && ionic run android
```

Later on, did a small edit on the index.html file and ran

```
ionic upload
```

Following the log, i found some file download tagged as `IONIC_DEPLOY_DOWNLOAD`, and as soon as the extract is complete, this error pops out

```
06-18 16:47:47.771: D/SystemWebViewClient(7128):
CordovaWebViewClient.onReceivedError: Error code=-1
Description=net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND 
URL=file:///data/data/com.org.app/app_eddaae501776ab76c86f69073/index.html



06-18 16:47:47.921: I/chromium(7128): 
[INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Not allowed to load local resource:
file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png", 
source: data:text/html,chromewebdata (0)
```

[image]

*EDIT*

Added log error

[image]

Comment: Do you have this plugin installed and configured: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist

Comment: Good catch! It seems to work on iOS, only problem is Android. I have added the <access origin="**" /> tag in config.xml as suggested here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#android-whitelisting

I placed it inside the <platform> tag

 <platform name="android">
        <allow-navigation href="*" />
        <access origin="*" />
    </platform>

What am i missing?

Comment: Also set this tag in index.HTML: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md#content-security-policy

Comment: Not even adding <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *"> to the index.html file i'm editing as test.

The last action is done by IONIC_DEPLOY_REDIRECT and the shown error is: 

06-19 14:02:42.908: D/CordovaWebViewImpl(5785): onPageDidNavigate(file:///data/data/com.org.app/app_eddaae501776ab76c86f69073/index.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem.

During the update on android, an internal error is generated by trying to create a directory that already exists.

In GIT has a fork that corrects this problem. (https://github.com/eweap/ionic-plugins-deploy).

To work. Execute the following commands:

```
$ Cord plug rm com.ionic.deploy
$ Cord plugin add https://github.com/eweap/ionic-plugins-deploy
$ Ionic platform removes android
$ Ionic platform add android
$ Ionic run android
```

Done!

Answer (score 0):

add this to your config.xml

```
<allow-navigation href="file://*/*"/>
```

and run without liveserver

with:

```
ionic emulate android
```